# Zsh new user install wont prompt

Tags: arch-linux, zsh

I just installed Zsh for the billionth time but for some reason the new user install prompt wont load, my terminal is maximized but no matter what it either doesn't run and says the command cant be found at all, im using Arch and ive tried installing it with pacman yay and paru but obviously it didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

```
autoload -Uz zsh-newuser-install; zsh-newuser-install -f
```